# can I assign a default value to a python while loop?

Tags: python

I've got a while loop of the form:

```
while temp is True:
    do stuff
    if the outcome is what I want:
        temp = False
```

I seem to use this construct quite often. So my question is whether there is a way I can initialise temp in the while statement itself, rather than have to precede this with `temp = True`?

Comment: Don't think so...

Comment: Don’t use `… is True`. Just write the expression itself. In your case, `while temp:`.

Comment: You don't need `temp` at all.

Comment: Depending on `do stuff`, you could put it in a function and return `True` when the outcome is what you want. Then the loop can be `while not do_stuff(): pass`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
while True:
    do stuff
    if the outcome is what I want:
        break
```